# Parsing fix logs for stock and price in column formats using grep /awk/UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

I have a fix log containing trade information such as:

```
  ==>  8=FIX4.2|39=1|55=IBM|6=138  
  ==>  8=FIX4.2|39=1|55=APPL|6=130  
  ==>  8=FIX4.2|39=1|55=GE|6=11
```

I'm trying to grep the output so that i can get something like this:

```
 IBM    138  
 APPL   130   
 GE     11
```

where the first column is IBM and the second column is 138.

I'm trying this:

```
grep 39=1 some.log | tr "|" "\n" | egrep '(^55=|^6=)'
```

but this only gets the stock/ price on separate lines like this:

```
IBM
AAPL
GE
138
130
11
```

Is there a bash/unix one liner that will get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F '[|=]' '{printf "%-6s %s\n", $8, $10}' file
```

Output:

```
IBM    138
APPL   130
GE     11
```

Comment: say i didnt know 8, 10 are the positions of those tags, what is the best way to get that ?

Comment: Please start a new question with this infomation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F '(55|6)=' -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/\|$/, "", $2); print $2, $3}' file
IBM     138
APPL    130
GE      11
```

Comment: I think you should add `/39=1`, since in question OP tried to `grep 39=1 some.log ` select lines with `39=1`

Comment: ok in that case OP can use: `awk -F '(55|6)=' -v OFS='\t' '/39=1/{sub(/\|$/, "", $2); print $2, $3}' file`

Answer (score 0):

GNU grep and paste:

```
grep -oP '\b(55|6)=\K[^|]+' file | paste  - -
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
grep '39=' filename | cut -d'|' -f3-4 | sed -e 's/55=//' -e 's/|6=/ /'
```