# Parsing fix logs for stock and price in column formats using grep /awk/UNIX without knowing position of fields

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a fix log containing trade information such as:

```
  ==>  8=FIX4.2|39=1|55=IBM|6=138  
  ==>  8=FIX4.2|39=1|55=APPL|6=130  
  ==>  8=FIX4.2|39=1|55=GE|6=11
```

I'm trying to grep the output so that i can get something like this:

```
 IBM    138  
 APPL   130   
 GE     11
```

where the first column is IBM and the second column is 138.

I'm trying this:

```
grep 39=1 some.log | tr "|" "\n" | egrep '(^55=|^6=)'
```

but this only gets the stock/ price on separate lines like this:

```
IBM
AAPL
GE
138
130
11
```

Is there a bash/unix one liner that will get this?

related to this this post

[Parsing fix logs for stock and price in column formats using grep /awk/UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058956/parsing-fix-logs-for-stock-and-price-in-column-formats-using-grep-awk-unix/31059315?noredirect=1#comment50304860_31059315)

This was solved with this answer:

```
awk -F '[|=]' '{printf "%-6s %s\n", $8, $10}' file
```

Say i didnt know 8, 10 are the positions of those tags, what is the best way to get that?

Comment: Are the `55=` and `6=` values always consecutive with `55=` first and not at the start of the line or could you have a file like `6=138|8=FIX4.2|55=IBM|39=1|55=IBM`? Edit your questions sample input/output to show all possible positions (start/mid/end) and orders of the 2 fields you care about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not what you asked I know, but have you considered `perl`?

Given what you're saying, it looks like you have named fields so something like this would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @cols = qw ( 55 6 );

while (<>) {
    my %data = m/(\d+)=([\w.]+)/g;
    print "@data{@cols}\n";
}
```

When given your input data, this prints:

```
IBM 138
APPL 130
GE 11
```

What it's doing is matching 'pairs' of keys and values with that regular expression, and turning each line into a hash table looking like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '55' => 'APPL',
          '8' => 'FIX4',
          '39' => '1',
          '6' => '130'
        };
```

And we tell it to extract the fields via a slice `@data{@cols}` says extract just the values of those two particular columns.

You could instead do:

```
print $data{55};
print $data{6};
```

Comment: thanks, this is scaleable solution for adding different tags

Answer (score 4):

This will do it but may be overkill as it'll work for all possible positions of either field:

```
$ gawk 'match($0,/(^|[|])55=([^|]+)/,name) && match($0,/(^|[|])6=([^|]+)/,value) {print name[2], value[2]}' file
IBM 138
APPL 130
GE 11
```

]It uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match().